How to validate a WSDL file?
I'm using zeep to parse this WSDL file from Debian's debbugs. Parsing the file seems to work (i.e.  no error), however when I try to execute a method, I get a stack trace because the port is missing (rather: the list of ports is empty). Apparently, zeep is unable to find or parse the Port from the document below. I'm not an expert in WSDL so I can't judge if this is a bug in zeep or an error in the WSDL file itself. I tried to find online validators for WSDL files, but couldn't find any.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wsdl:definitions
    name="DebbugsSoap"
    targetNamespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
    xmlns:tns="urn:DebbugsSoap"
    xmlns:types="urn:DebbugsSoapTypes"
    xmlns:apachens="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

  <wsdl:types>
    <schema targetNamespace="urn:DebbugsSoapTypes"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>

      <complexType name="ArrayOfBugNumber">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:int[]"/>
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
       </complexType>

      <complexType name="ArrayOfAnyType">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:anyType[]"/>
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
       </complexType>

      <complexType name="ArrayOfArrayOfAnyType">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType"
               wsdl:arrayType="types:ArrayOfAnyType[]"/>
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
       </complexType>

      <complexType name="ArrayOfArrayOfArrayOfAnyType">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType"
               wsdl:arrayType="types:ArrayOfArrayOfAnyType[]"/>
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
       </complexType>
    </schema>

    <schema targetNamespace="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>

      <complexType name="mapItem">
        <sequence>
          <element name="key" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
          <element name="value" nillable="true" type="xsd:anyType"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>

      <complexType name="Map">
        <sequence>
          <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"
           name="item" type="apachens:mapItem"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
    </schema>
  </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="get_statusRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="bugs" type="types:ArrayOfBugNumber"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="get_statusResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="s-gensym3" type="apachens:Map"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="get_bug_logRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="bugnumber" type="xsd:int"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="get_bug_logResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="soapenc:Array" type="types:ArrayOfAnyType"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="get_bugsRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="query" type="types:ArrayOfAnyType"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="get_bugsResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="soapenc:Array" type="types:ArrayOfBugNumber"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="get_usertagRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="user" type="xsd:string"/>
    <!-- We do not support tags -->
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="get_usertagResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="s-gensym3" type="xsd:anyType"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="newest_bugsRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="amount" type="xsd:int"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="newest_bugsResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="soapenc:Array" type="types:ArrayOfBugNumber"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="binary_to_sourceRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="arguments" type="types:ArrayOfAnyType"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="binary_to_sourceResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="soapenc:Array" type="types:ArrayOfAnyType"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="source_to_binaryRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="source_name" type="xsd:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="source_version" type="xsd:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="source_to_binaryResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="soapenc:Array" type="types:ArrayOfAnyType"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="get_versionsRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="arguments" type="types:ArrayOfAnyType"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="get_versionsResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="soapenc:Array" type="types:ArrayOfAnyType"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="DebbugsSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="get_status" parameterOrder="bugs">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:get_statusRequest">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:get_statusResponse">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="get_bug_log" parameterOrder="bugnumber">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:get_bug_logRequest">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:get_bug_logResponse">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="get_bugs" parameterOrder="query">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:get_bugsRequest">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:get_bugsResponse">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="get_usertag" parameterOrder="user">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:get_usertagRequest">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:get_usertagResponse">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="newest_bugs" parameterOrder="amount">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:newest_bugsRequest">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:newest_bugsResponse">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="binary_to_source" parameterOrder="arguments">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:binary_to_sourceRequest">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:binary_to_sourceResponse">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="source_to_binary" parameterOrder="source_name source_version">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:source_to_binaryRequest">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:source_to_binaryResponse">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="get_versions" parameterOrder="arguments">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:get_versionsRequest">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:get_versionsResponse">
        <soap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:binding name="DebbugsSoapBinding" type="tns:DebbugsSoap">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="get_status">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="DebbugsSoap"/>
      <wsdl:input name="get_statusRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="get_statusResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="get_bug_log">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="DebbugsSoap"/>
      <wsdl:input name="get_bug_logRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="get_bug_logResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="get_bugs">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="DebbugsSoap"/>
      <wsdl:input name="get_bugsRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="get_bugsResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="get_usertag">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="DebbugsSoap"/>
      <wsdl:input name="get_tagRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="get_tagResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="newest_bugs">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="DebbugsSoap"/>
      <wsdl:input name="newest_bugsRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="newest_bugsResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="binary_to_source">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="DebbugsSoap"/>
      <wsdl:input name="binary_to_sourceRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="binary_to_sourceResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="source_to_binary">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="DebbugsSoap"/>
      <wsdl:input name="source_to_binaryRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="source_to_binaryResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="get_versions">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="DebbugsSoap"/>
      <wsdl:input name="get_versionsRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="get_versionsResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="urn:DebbugsSoap"
        use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:service name="DebbugsSoapService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:DebbugsSoapBinding" name="debian.org">
      <wsdlsoap:address location="https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/soap.cgi"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>



Download https://www.soapui.org/tools/soapui/, save the WSDL to a file, then open it with SoapUI. If it's malformed, SoapUI will complain and fail to generate any service or sample requests.
